# SPRING and gradle project

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I use spring tools suite STS  3.9.1  and I have import a project gradle of my old computer to new computer.
When I use click right context menu 'Refresh Gradle Project' it build sucessfully but i don't see a external library in my treeview project and I can't publish to tomcat and start tomcat.

What's the problem ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: *I can't publish to tomcat and start tomcat.* Does it show a message?

Comment: no, he does not recognize that it's an application gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact , for my mind , the solution is to launch the Build or Build Depends task, and in a file log, I have a problem of certificat SSL in my cacerts

so it's all good

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can execute this command gradlew eclipse or ./gradlew eclipse and then export the project